# How to find the second greatest element in a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, generics

Suppose we have a class (SomeClass) with two fields, an ID of type int and a date of type DateTime.

Now imagine that there is a list of SomeClass ordered by date and we need to find the second to last element of the list. How would we do this with [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)?

Comment: Only one element of the list. The one with 2nd highest Date and ONLY that element. Example: A list of 5 "SomeClasses" have these dates 1/1/2001, 1/1/2003, 1/1/2009, 1/1/2010, 1/1/2012. I want the ID of the SomeClass with the date of 1/1/2010

Comment: Now an important question....are the dates always going to be in order?  If not, are you after the second most recent date?

Comment: The dates will always be in ascending order from a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var nextToLast = list.Skip(list.Count - 2).First();
```

as @Brizio points out, you can use good ol' indexing too

```
var nextToLast = list[list.Count - 2];
```

Comment: You can also use the Count() extension method in order to have it work with IEnumerables too. There should be no performance hit for IList.

Comment: I'd suggest doing this on IEnumerables is dangerous, as you don't know the side effects.

Comment: May I suggest that if he's already using a list a simple list[list.Count - 2] could suffice without all the fuss of iterating over a sequence? I am assuming that he's using enumerables all the way long, otherwise the request wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @Brizio suggestion added!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one for the second place:

In your comparison:

```
public class YourCustomClassComparer : IComparer<YourObject> {
    public int Compare(YourObject x, YourObject y) {
        //do whatever you need to do to compare
    }
}
```

and your method (this will grab the second in the list)

```
var result = list.OrderBy(a => a, new YourCustomClassCompairer()).ElementAt(1);
```

And if you wanted the inverse (which i noticed in your question), do the following

```
var result = list.OrderByDescending(a => a, new YourCustomClassCompairer()).ElementAt(1);
```